# JQuery Increment/Decrement value depending on selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug, increment, decrement

I am mostly there but cant seem to crack this, I have a simple form with check boxes,

```
form#bookingsToDelete(
            action='/list/batchDelete'
            method='POST'
            autocomplete='off'
            )
            tbody
              each doc in list
                -var id = doc._id;
                tr
                  td 
                    input.form-control(type='checkbox' name='ids[]' id='doc._id' value=doc._id onclick='return selectedForDelete();' )
                  td.bg-blue= doc.tourDate
                  td
```

and a counter which should update depending on how many boxes have been selected. Using below JQuery I am able to increment up but when I click a selected checkbox (to deselect the item) it wont increment down by one and I don't understand why.

```
div.p-2.actionMenu-2.float-right
            button.btn.btn-danger(type='submit' form='bookingsToDelete' value='Submit')
              span Delete 
              span.deleteCounter.badge.badge-light
```

custom.js

```
let bcount ='1';
function selectedForDelete() {
  if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked') ) {
    $('input:checkbox:checked').addClass('checked');
    $('.deleteCounter').text( bcount ++ );
  } else {
    $('input:checkbox').removeClass('checked');
    $('.deleteCounter').text( bcount -- );
  }
}
```

I have tried `bcount +1` `bcount -1` and moving the var declaration inside the function. If I click only one checkbox the counter increments up and down but as soon as I select multiple check boxes the counter goes up but doesn't go down when I deselect the box.

Please, any guidance would b much appreciated!

Comment: `$('input:checkbox).is(':checked')` returns the state of the first checkbox in the document. It ignores all the other elements matched by the selector.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to assist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because your jQuery selector in the `if` condition, `$('input:checkbox')` is selecting *all* the checkboxes in the page. When you then call `is()` on that it only interrogates the checked state of the *first* one.

To fix this you need to get a reference to the element which raised the change event. The best way to do that is to attach your event handlers unobtrusively. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var bcount = 1;

  $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.prop('checked')) {
      $el.addClass('checked');
      $('.deleteCounter').text(++bcount);
    } else {
      $el.removeClass('checked');
      $('.deleteCounter').text(--bcount);
    }
  });
});
```

*However* this is still not optimal. It's not DRY and it contains a global variable (global within the scope of jQuery's document.ready handler anyway). A better approach would be to simply count the number of checked boxes under each event. You can also avoid the addition/removal of the class by simply using the `:checked` selector in CSS

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $('.deleteCounter').text($('input:checkbox:checked').length);
  });
});
```

```css
input:checked {
  /* your styling here... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly and now I understand how I went wrong more importantly. Thank you for taking time from your day! PS I love that using `.on(change)` I don't need to add/remove classes anymore!

Comment: @ZADorkMan Rory also changed your counter display from *display-then-increment* (`bcount ++`) to *increment-then-display* (`++bcount`).

Comment: @freginold thank you for the catch! I had JUST been reading about passing increment or decrement before or after vars so I should have noticed that.